# Accessing a value from a nested array in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, nested, frontend

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('./movies.JSON');
data.toString();
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(Object.values(obj.moviesList));
```

This is my js file. This prints all keys and pairs of my JSON file. I am trying to access the nested array in the JSON file. I have tried `console.log(Object.values(obj.moviesList.actors==="206'));`

And a bunch of  other variations.

```
    "moviesList":[
    {
        "movieId": 4192148,
        "title": "Highly Functional",
        "actors": [
            3188187,
            3306943,
            132257,
            47265
        ]
    },
```

here is a small snippet of my JSON file containing nested arrays.

I want to start out by printing out all movie Id's that have an actor whose id is 206.

Answer (score 1):

If you are scanning a nested array, here's one way to about that using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check the actors array.

```js
const moviesList = [{
    "movieId": 4192148,
    "title": "Highly Functional",
    "actors": [
      3188187,
      3306943,
      132257,
      47265
    ]
  },
  {
    "movieId": 11111,
    "title": "Highly Functional2",
    "actors": [
      3188187,
      3306943,
      206,
      47265
    ]
  },
  {
    "movieId": 11112,
    "title": "Highly Functional3",
    "actors": [
      3188187,
      3306943,
      206,
      47265
    ]
  }
];

let matches = [];
for (const movie of moviesList) {
  const { actors, movieId } = movie;
  if (actors.includes(206)) {
    matches.push(movieId);
  }
}

console.log(matches);

// Another format

matches = moviesList
  .filter(({ actors }) => actors.includes(206))
  .map(({ movieId }) => movieId)
  
  
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: but wouldn't that snippet result in moviesList being undefined since you never read in the JSON file?

Comment: I do not have your movies.json file not nor can I run node.js in the browser. However, hopefully this shows how to filter that data for the actor ID of interest, once the JSON is parsed, and you have a reference to moviesList array to start with.

Comment: Thanks ill see what i can do with this!